# How can I specify OAS3.1 query parameter `style` with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi

In my API I want to have a query parameter containing a list from an `enum`, and I want to specify the [`style` for the parameter as `form`](https://swagger.io/specification/#style-values), i.e. the OAS spec would be akin to:

```yaml
paths:
  /api/items:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: classes
          style: form
          in: query
          required: false
          schema:
            anyOf:
              - type: array
                items:
                  type: string
                  enum:
                    - classA
                    - classB
                    - classC
              - type: "null"
```

And, one valid call might be `GET /api/items?classes=classB,classC`

It doesn't seem like FastAPI supports this presently and there are two unresolved issues related to this

- https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/8940
- https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/8322

So I am wondering how the community is handling this kind of scenario, is there a preferred workaround?